# Android widget based on html5

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I am trying to develop a widget (just a widget not a widget based on an app itself) for android which works on html and javascript. However, I do not know if I can do it.
Is this possible?
Kind Regards,
Daniel

Comment: have you tried WebView?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by a "widget"? Do you mean a subclass of `View` that is used by an activity or fragment? Do you mean an app widget, that goes on the home screen? Do you mean something else? What do you mean by "not a widget based on an app itself"?

Comment: I mean a widget that goes on the homescreen... What I mean but not based on an app is that I dont want to have an app which has a widget (some apps use it like for quick controls)..

Answer (score 2):

> I mean a widget that goes on the homescreen

You cannot create an app widget that uses JavaScript. You may be able to use `Html.fromHtml()` for some limited HTML support in a `TextView`, but it is very limited (e.g., no CSS).

> I dont want to have an app which has a widget

All app widgets are part of apps. It is not possible to have an app widget that is not part of some app.

Answer (score 0):

To export it into a Widget I would go for PhoneGap. You can export your HTML5 JavaSript applications to native application on all platforms.

Although, apparently for widgets you will have to use a fair bit of native code aswell.